# Adding Information to Component Failing, XPath, Node Type Error

Tags: cme, javascript

Randomly today, trying to insert a schema or component into another component in cme is failing. A look at the console in Chrome shows the following errors when click event is fired from insert button:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: XPathResult is not defined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE' of undefined
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this chrome only? Can you try another browser? Just trying to figure if it's a server or browser issue

Comment: This looks like a chromium issue - can you confirm the version of Chrome you're using (and if an update took place between this working and not) - this will help to warn others of a potential issue. Then, as Nuno says - try i n another browser type (IE / Firefox) and confirm is all is well there?

Comment: So far I have been unable to replicate this error in Firefox or IE. It still does occur in Chrome with all extensions disabled. I am using chrome  41.0.2272.118 the latest version. It also occurred on the last version of chrome I was using, which I'm sorry I don't know which version that was.